# Matching up iterables in lists, having significant difficulty

Tags: python, arrays, iterable

For a personal project I have three lists. One of these contains a set of arrays (l2) the size of which is always determined by a setting l2_size and always contains random members of l1. The next array, l3, on the other hand will always be a set of 0's of quantity len(l1).

This means...

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]
l2 = [[3, 4, 5, 2, 4],[3, 5, 1, 2, 4], [4, 3, 2, 1, 5]]
l3 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

I need to perform a search such that

1. Beginning with l2[0] if the pointer l2[0] hits l2[0], search through l1 to find l1[i] == the first value of l2[0].
2. Once the first value of l2[0] use l3 to assign its corresponding value.
3. Since the size of the arrays in l2[0] are 5 members we are going to assign a corresponding value of 1 to l3 a maximum of five times. Once we have hit that target we're moving onto the next set l2[1].
4. Once we are done with l2[0] (so on to l2[1]) we need to assign the next corresponding value, so 2, without over-writing the values in l3.

**Illustration...**

Imagine these are baseball scoring cards... I have l1 baseball cards in my deck. The compositions of baseball scoring cards I want in my hands are contained in l2. These cards will win me the game! In this case l2 = [1,2,3,4,5]. I'm a massive cheater and must find all l2 in l1 (cards for hands). Finding l2 in l1 I mark where they are using l3. I also use l3 to tell me which hand to put them in.

To be a valid solution we must uniquely pair up the values in l2 such that they are uniquely identified as values in l1 using l3. This would mean...

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]
l2 = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]
l3 = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2]
```

Would be valid. But...

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]
l2 = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]
l3 = [1,2,1,1,1,2,2,1,2,2]
```

Would be invalid because there is no hand in l2 containing [2,1,2,4,5] in any order.

**Example**

From l2[0] we are going to iterate through l1 over and over and pick up all the objects in l2[0] and sign them off to l3. This should then look like (by hand)...

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]
l2 = [[3, 4, 5, 2, 4],[3, 5, 1, 2, 4], [4, 3, 2, 1, 5]]
l3 = [0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

The value 1 has been assigned in l3 since these are the first instances of the corresponding values we come across. We are done with l2[0] now because we have found all of its items in l1. The next job is l2[1]...

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]
l2 = [[3, 4, 5, 2, 4],[3, 5, 1, 2, 4], [4, 3, 2, 1, 5]]
l3 = [2,2,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,2,2,2]
```

This is what I've cooked up but to no avail...

```
assignvar = 1
pos = 0
for x in l2:
    for y in x:
        for z in l1:
            while userpos < len(l1):
                if y == z:
                    l1[pos] = assignvar
                    while l2_size == pos:
                        assignvar += 1
                        l2_size = l2_size+l2_size #stops pos going out of range, changes assignvar to 2 (so appending the next set of l3 iterables to 2 .etc)
                userpos = userpos+1
```

Really quite confounded how to approach this issue in my code. I feel like I have the right idea using the three for loops but I've been hitting this with my wrench for a while now and completely burned out.

**Real world input dataset...**

```
l1 = [5005.0, 5002.5, 5003.0, 5003.0, 5003.5, 5002.5, 5003.5, 5004.0, 5004.5, 5004.0, 5002.5, 5005.0, 5004.5, 5004.0, 5005.0, 5002.5, 5003.5, 5004.0, 5002.5, 5002.5, 5004.0, 5004.0, 5003.5, 5001.5, 5001.5, 5005.0, 5003.0, 5005.0, 5003.5, 5000.5, 5002.5, 5003.5, 5005.0]

l2 = [[5002.5, 5004.0], [5002.5, 5004.5], [5002.5, 5004.0], [5002.5, 5005.0], [5002.5, 5004.5], [5002.5, 5004.0], [5002.5, 5005.0], [5002.5, 5004.0], [5002.5, 5004.0], [5002.5, 5004.0], [5002.5, 5005.0], [5002.5, 5005.0], [5002.5, 5005.0], [5003.0, 5003.5], [5003.0, 5003.5], [5003.0, 5004.0], [5003.0, 5004.5], [5003.0, 5004.0], [5003.0, 5005.0], [5003.0, 5004.5], [5003.0, 5004.0], [5003.0, 5005.0], [5003.0, 5003.5], [5003.0, 5004.0], [5003.0, 5004.0], [5003.0, 5004.0], [5003.0, 5003.5], [5003.0, 5005.0], [5003.0, 5005.0], [5003.0, 5003.5], [5003.0, 5003.5], [5003.0, 5005.0], [5003.0, 5003.5], [5003.0, 5003.5], [5003.0, 5004.0], [5003.0, 5004.5], [5003.0, 5004.0], [5003.0, 5005.0], [5003.0, 5004.5], [5003.0, 5004.0], [5003.0, 5005.0], [5003.0, 5003.5], [5003.0, 5004.0], [5003.0, 5004.0], [5003.0, 5004.0], [5003.0, 5003.5], [5003.0, 5005.0], [5003.0, 5005.0], [5003.0, 5003.5], [5003.0, 5003.5], [5003.0, 5005.0], [5002.5, 5004.0], [5002.5, 5004.5], [5002.5, 5004.0], [5002.5, 5005.0], [5002.5, 5004.5], [5002.5, 5004.0], [5002.5, 5005.0], [5002.5, 5004.0], [5002.5, 5004.0], [5002.5, 5004.0], [5002.5, 5005.0], [5002.5, 5005.0], [5002.5, 5005.0], [5002.5, 5005.0], [5002.5, 5004.5], [5002.5, 5004.0], [5002.5, 5005.0], [5002.5, 5004.0], [5002.5, 5004.0], [5002.5, 5004.0], [5002.5, 5005.0], [5002.5, 5005.0], [5002.5, 5005.0], [5002.5, 5004.0], [5002.5, 5004.0], [5002.5, 5004.0], [5002.5, 5005.0], [5002.5, 5005.0], [5002.5, 5005.0], [5002.5, 5004.0], [5002.5, 5004.0], [5002.5, 5005.0], [5002.5, 5005.0], [5002.5, 5005.0], [5002.5, 5004.0], [5002.5, 5004.0], [5002.5, 5005.0], [5002.5, 5005.0], [5002.5, 5005.0], [5001.5, 5005.0], [5001.5, 5005.0], [5001.5, 5005.0], [5001.5, 5005.0], [5001.5, 5005.0], [5001.5, 5005.0], [5003.0, 5005.0], [5003.0, 5003.5], [5003.0, 5003.5], [5003.0, 5005.0], [5002.5, 5005.0]]

l3=[]
for i in range(len(l1)):
    l3.append(int(0))
```

Comment: First of all, which of the three lists `l1`, `l2`, `l3` are the inputs to the function that you're trying to write and which are the outputs? Also, can you write what the output should be for an example input?

Comment: Or, to put it another way: I was about to assume that you take `l1` and `l2` and produce `l3` based on that, but then I saw that you're modifying `l1` but not `l3` in your code. Is that a typo?  If it is just a typo, what do you expect `l3` to be at the end?

Comment: So l1 and l2 and l3 are all example inputs as they are all arrays which already exist. I need to keep looping over l1 using l2 until I have the correct configuration for l3. I have put an example on the edited post. Illustration: put your finger on the first item of l2 and go left to right in l1 (in a loop) until you find it. If you do find it then move on to the next iterable l2[1] and go over and over l1 again until you find l2[1] then give it the appropriate value for l3 (which would be 1).

Comment: Looking at your example, it seems like none of the elements in l2 will be found so your expected output is `[0]*11`. Perhaps you could provide a more clear example with expected output, since your code does not seem to correspond with your description.

Comment: Just realized I forgot to highlight the value from l1 (so it can't be iterated over again once it's been given a value in l3), will probably need another array to do this. Going to give this 10 minutes before I hit it with my wrench some more.

Comment: Please see baseball card illustration above.

Comment: So I still don't understand, is this what you want?:  each element in ```l3``` corresponds to the element in ```l1``` with the same index, ```l2``` represents *hands*, starting with the first *hand* in ```l2``` you want to match its cards to their first occurance in ```l1``` and for each that has a match you want to assign the *hand number* to the  corresponding  element in ```l3```, once an element in ```l1``` has been *used* for a hand it cannot be *used* again.  Does that sound right?

Comment: @wwii Yes that's exactly right, however unfortunately the solution (below) could not handle the test dataset "Real World input dataset". I reckoned I could just do it with for loops, but clearly this is becoming quite the mystery!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified the solution by creating two arrays extra arrays called a "configuration space" which are assigned boolean true (represented by the integer 1) depending on a number (a card) has been assigned to a hand or a member of the subset (a hand) has already been assigned to a card.

This solution makes one trip over l2, then makes a trip through l1, and assigns a card to a hand in l3 only if both the hand and card are unassigned (as indicated 0 in each array in configuration space).

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5] #Total number of players
l2 = [[3, 4, 5, 2, 4],[3, 5, 1, 2, 4], [4, 3, 2, 1, 5]] #Possible teams
l3 = [] #Assigned teams
for i in range(len(l1)):
    l3.append(int(0))
##############################################################################################################################################################
#Configuration space. Responsible for indicating whether (a) a player from l1 has been assigned to a team or (b) a team has already been assigned to a player#
##############################################################################################################################################################

playerbase_configurationspace = []
matchmadeteams_configurationspace = [] #detects if value in l2 has been assigned (if going over a number which has been given value 1 but we need to give it value 2)

for i in range(len(l1)):
    playerbase_configurationspace.append(int(0))
for x in l2:
    for y in x:
        matchmadeteams_configurationspace.append(int(0))


teamsize = len(l2[0])
teamcount = len(l2[0])
assignteam = 1 #Base no. of teams to be assigned


################################
#Flatten list of lists##########
################################

matchmadeteams_processed = []
for x in l2:
    for y in x:
        matchmadeteams_processed.append(y)


####################################################################################################################################
#Teammate handler: makes lookups into the configuration space to help determine whether either a player has been assigned to a team#
####################################################################################################################################

def teammate_handler(isnotfreeplayer,isnotfreeslot, assignteam):

    if playerbase_configurationspace[isnotfreeplayer] == 0 and matchmadeteams_configurationspace[isnotfreeslot] == 0:
        playerbase_configurationspace[isnotfreeplayer] = 1
        matchmadeteams_configurationspace[isnotfreeslot] = 1                                     
        return int(1), assignteam #Outcome 1, safe to add player to empty slot, assign == value to be assigned

    #else either, player is set team, teammate of team is set team (or both):: do nothing
    elif playerbase_configurationspace[isnotfreeplayer] == 1 and matchmadeteams_configurationspace[isnotfreeslot] == 0:
        return int(2) #Outcome 2, continue the for loop iterating through players since the player is not free but the slot is free
    elif playerbase_configurationspace[isnotfreeplayer] == 0 and matchmadeteams_configurationspace[isnotfreeslot] == 1:
        return int(3) #Outcome 3, break the for loop iterating through slots and players since the slot is not free
    elif playerbase_configurationspace[isnotfreeplayer] == 1 and matchmadeteams_configurationspace[isnotfreeslot] == 1:
        return int(4)
    return int(5) #Unexpected error (catch all)

###############################

for teammatepos in enumerate(matchmadeteams_processed):
    print(teamcount)
    if teamcount == 0:
        assignteam += 1
        teamcount = teamsize
    for playerpos in enumerate(l1):
        if playerpos[1] == teammatepos[1]:
            print("Match, using player"+str(playerpos)+" teammate"+str(teammatepos))
            print ()
            print ("Teammate "+str(teammatepos), matchmadeteams_processed)
            print ("Player "+str(playerpos), l1)
            print ("")
            if teammate_handler(playerpos[0], teammatepos[0], assignteam) == (1, assignteam):
                l3[playerpos[0]] = assignteam
                print ("I have assigned teams to this player")
            else:
                continue
        else:
            continue
    teamcount -= 1
print(l3)
```

Comment: The initial *construction* of ```l3``` could be refactored to either ```l3 = [0]*len(l1)``` or (probably more pleasing to the eye) ```l3 = [0 for thing in l1]```. Same comment for ```playerbase_configurationspace```.

Comment: Similarly ```matchmadeteams_configurationspace = [0 for x in l2 for y in x]```

Answer (score 2):

get sublist first, then using sublist's element get l1's index. increase 1 for l3 element based on l1's index

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]
l2 = [[3, 4, 5, 2, 4],[3, 5, 1, 2, 4], [4, 3, 2, 1, 5]]
l3 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

def combinList( lst ):
    ''' put list of list together based on index
        for example:
        a = [1,3,5,7]
        b = [2,4,6,8]
        combined list should be [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] '''
    step = len(lst)
    res= [None]*len(  reduce(lambda x,y:x+y, lst))
    for i,item in enumerate(lst):
        res[i::step] = sorted(item)
    return res


for value,line in enumerate(l2):
    counter = 0 
    record = {} 
    # count how many time this element appeared 
    for i in line:
        record[ i -1 ] = record.get( i - 1,0) + 1
    newList = combinList( [ [ i for i,j in enumerate(l1) if item == j] for item in line ] )
    for idx in newList:
        # if this element of l3 hasn't been change and there is at least one associated element in l2,put the value to l3 and reduce the number of l2
        if not l3[idx] and record.get(idx%5,0):
            l3[idx] = value + 1
            counter+=1
            record[idx%5] = record[idx%5] -1
        if counter >=5:
            break 
    print l3
print l3
```

output:

```
#first iteration 
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
#second iteration 
[2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0]
#third iteration 
[2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 3, 3, 2, 3]
#final iteration 
[2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 3, 3, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Your ```l3``` doesn't look like the OP's desired ```l3```.

Comment: Made significant edits to hopefully illustrate better.

Comment: @mmacheerpuppy  I don't get it. l2[0] has 2,so after first iteration the result should be [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]. right?

Comment: @mmacheerpuppy I mean when should assign a value to l3 is not clear

Comment: Imagine these are baseball scoring cards... I have l1 baseball cards in my deck. The compositions of baseball scoring cards I want in my hands are contained in l2. These cards will win me the game! In this case l2 = [1,2,3,4,5]. I'm a massive cheater and must find all l2 in l1 (cards for hands). Finding l2 in l1 I mark where they are using l3. I also use l3 to tell me which hand to put them in. Thus, if l1 = [1,2,3,4,5] and l2 = [1,2,3,4,5] I mark l3 as = [1,1,1,1,1] because I've went through my hand to find what I'm looking for. I hope this clears things up for you.

Comment: I think the baseball card example is a good one so I've put it in the main body.

Comment: @mmacheerpuppy updated code, but still can not get the result you want.  I think the output is valid result

Comment: I think that might be right. Give me 10 minutes to run this through the bulk.

Comment: Beautiful! This resolved the issue... In your example all lists l2 cleared with one member 4 remainder, and one member 1 unassigned; so both are headed by a value of 0 in l3 (which is valid)! Thank you so much. Would you mind commenting the blocks to help me understand what you did here. I humbly apologize for the trouble caused getting the point across: coding on 3 hours sleep. I'm going to do the best I can to learn from what you've done.

Comment: Looks like ```combinList``` takes a list-of-lists as an argument, sorts each sublists, transposes the results and *flattens* it.  I think it could be refactored as ```def foo(list_of_lists): list_of_lists = map(sorted, list_of_lists);  return [x for thing in zip(*list_of_lists) for x in thing]```

Comment: Unfortunately this couldn't handle my monsterously large dataset (which is one of many that I've put on the main post). Any more ideas :(?

Comment: I got an output of...

[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Using that algorithm.

Comment: Hey guys just letting you know I've posted a resolution. Let me know what you think, in particular how I can re-factor the code!

Answer (score 0):

Still a little hazy on the specs but try this - it works for the simple case of `l1 = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]` and `l2 = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]`.

```
used_indices = set()

def get_next_index(card, l1 = l1, used_indices = used_indices):
    try:
        # find the next index that has not been used
        index = l1.index(card)
        while index in used_indices:
            # if the index has already been used, find the next one
            index = l1.index(card, index + 1)
    except ValueError as e:
        # this card cannot be found
        print('hand:{}, card:{} not found'.format(hand_no, card))
        index = None
    return index


for hand_no, hand in enumerate(l2, 1):
    for card in hand:
        index = get_next_index(card)
        if index:
            l3[index] = hand_no
            used_indices.add(index)
```

Comment: So on the bigger data-range we are getting... [4, 1, 14, 15, 14, 2, 15, 1, 2, 3, 3, 7, 5, 6, 11, 4, 23, 8, 5, 6, 9, 10, 27, 91, 92, 12, 16, 13, 30, 0, 7, 31, 19].  At that point it's very unclear how we're ending up with these bigger numbers such as 92. In the case of the last integer of l1, it's been around the loop 31 times. We don't need to satisfy *every winning hand* (l2) just as long as we assign each item in l1 *a hand* (based on any possible set of hands in l3) this is sufficient. I suppose if we can't assign l1 a hand based on l2 I'd say it is best to append 0.

Comment: @mmacheerpuppy - so are you saying that the elements of ```l3``` only get assigned to a *hand* if All of the *cards* in a hand can be found in ```l1```??

Comment: Yes. Maybe poker hands might best illustrate i.e. if was searching through my list of cards l1 and got a royal flush according to my hands l2 then I need to assign the value of 1 to l3 as if I'm taking those cards out of card stack l1 and assigning them to the potential hand l2.

Comment: Quite excited for tomorrow. I had a crazy set of for loops and lists on lists and all this cross referencing going on but just had a great thought: "why on earth am I limiting myself to just the 3 lists". I can simply create another 2 lists l4 and l5 and use them for boolean true and false (has a card in l1 already been assigned a hand, or has this subset  or hand in l2 already got all of its values). Far more pythonic than what I'm trying to do now, I'll get to it in my lunch break at work!

Comment: Hey guys just letting you know I've posted a resolution. Let me know what you think, in particular how I can re-factor the code!